# Sorting htmlcollection by title

Tags: javascript, html

vanilla javascript starter here.
I'm trying to sort some of my elements that I have in a list. After browsing a lot of existing solutions but getting none of them to work I think it's an issue that I don't know how to formulate what I'm looking for so maybe someone more experienced can help me out.

So I'm trying to get my list sorted alphabetically and then changed in the htmlcollection.
the items look like this:

```
      <li class="foodListItem" title = "potato">
        <div class="img">
          <a href="" title="potato">
            <img src = "FoodImages/potato.jpg" alt="Potato">
          </a>
        </div>
        <p class="name">
          <a href="" title="potato"> Potato</a>
        </p>
      </li>
      <li class="foodListItem" title="brocolli">
        <div class="img">
          <a href="" title="brocolli">
            <img src = "FoodImages/brocolli.jpg" alt="brocolli">
          </a>
        </div>
        <p class="name">
          <a href="" title="brocolli"> brocolli</a>
        </p>
      </li>
```

And the closest I've gotten to replacing it has been this approach:

```
function sortImages()
{
    var foodList= document.getElementsByClassName("foodListItem");
    foodArray = Array.from(foodList);
    foodArray.sort(function (a, b){
        if(a.title < b.title)
        {
            return -1;
        }
        if(a.title > b.title){
            return 1;
        }
        return 0;
    });
    for(var i = 0; i < foodArray.length; i++)
    {
        foodList[i].replaceWith(foodArray[i]);
    }
}
```

With this approach however I seem to be losing elements whilst replacing them and otherwise I haven't gotten it to replace correctly using other methods.
Anyone know a better solution?

Comment: You should try and use foodArray instead of foodList in the last for loop at the end

Comment: @Deano do you mean to change foodList[i].replaceWith.. to foodArray[i].replaceWith(foodList[i])? This seems to have results I understand even less :')

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`replaceWith()` truncates the live list: a given HTML element instance can exist in a document only once, so if you replace `x` with `y`, then `x` is actually moved, it disappears from its original location, and thus the HTMLCollection becomes one element shorter. This way the loop fails around the middle (there may be cases when an element replaces itself), and the original list is approximately halved:

```js
function sortImages()
{
    var foodList= document.getElementsByTagName("div");
    foodArray = Array.from(foodList);
    foodArray.sort((a, b)=>a.innerText.localeCompare(b.innerText));
    for(var i = 0; i < foodArray.length; i++)
    {
        foodList[i].replaceWith(foodArray[i]);
    }
}
```

```html
<div>q</div>
<div>w</div>
<div>e</div>
<div>r</div>
<div>t</div>
<div>y</div>
<div>u</div>
<div>i</div>
<div>o</div>
<div>p</div>
<div>a</div>
<div>s</div>
<div>d</div>
<div>f</div>
<button onclick="sortImages()">Clicky</button>
```

As it's a live collection, it has no explicit add operation, but technically you can extend the document itself, though I wouldn't call that intuitive: check if `i` went past `length`, and use `insertAdjacentElement()` when it does:

```js
function sortImages()
{
    var foodList= document.getElementsByTagName("div");
    foodArray = Array.from(foodList);
    foodArray.sort((a, b)=>a.innerText.localeCompare(b.innerText));
    for(var i = 0; i < foodArray.length; i++)
    {
        if(i<foodList.length)
          foodList[i].replaceWith(foodArray[i]);
        else
          foodList[i-1].insertAdjacentElement("afterend",foodArray[i]);
    }
}
```

```html
<div>q</div>
<div>w</div>
<div>e</div>
<div>r</div>
<div>t</div>
<div>y</div>
<div>u</div>
<div>i</div>
<div>o</div>
<div>p</div>
<div>a</div>
<div>s</div>
<div>d</div>
<div>f</div>
<button onclick="sortImages()">Clicky</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can actually benefit from `getElementsByXy()` methods returning live collections. Then you have to find a way to move the items around. A method which I remember is [`Node.insertBefore()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/insertBefore), which allows kind-of bubble sort (I didn't fully think through if it's really a bubble sort):

```js
function doThing(){
  const inputs=document.getElementsByTagName("li");
  for(let i=0;i<inputs.length-1;i++) {
    const item=inputs[i];
    for(let j=i+1;j<inputs.length;j++){
      const jtem=inputs[j];
      if(item.firstChild.value>jtem.firstChild.value)
        item.parentNode.insertBefore(jtem,item);
    }
  }
}
```

```html
<ul>
<li><input oninput="doThing()"></li>
<li><input oninput="doThing()"></li>
<li><input oninput="doThing()"></li>
<li><input oninput="doThing()"></li>
<li><input oninput="doThing()"></li>
<li><input oninput="doThing()"></li>
</ul>
```

Now as I looked into it, there is [`Element.insertAdjacentElement()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/insertAdjacentElement) which doesn't need the `parentNode` ugliness, and would allow `after` too (not used here):

```js
function doThing(){
  const inputs=document.getElementsByTagName("li");
  for(let i=0;i<inputs.length-1;i++) {
    const item=inputs[i];
    for(let j=i+1;j<inputs.length;j++){
      const jtem=inputs[j];
      if(item.firstChild.value>jtem.firstChild.value)
        item.insertAdjacentElement("beforebegin",jtem);
    }
  }
}
```

```html
<ul>
<li><input oninput="doThing()"></li>
<li><input oninput="doThing()"></li>
<li><input oninput="doThing()"></li>
<li><input oninput="doThing()"></li>
<li><input oninput="doThing()"></li>
<li><input oninput="doThing()"></li>
</ul>
```

Comment: You mentioned that htmlcollections is a live collection, does that mean it would be more like a reference where it gets updated immediately when it would get altered anywhere else as well?

Comment: Yes, that's what this snippet makes use of: there's a single `getElements...` at the beginning, yet it's used for comparison in nested loops, which do reorder the list.

Comment: Is there a function  that would get the same elements whilst not being live. Since that is I think why I am losing the last element in my current setup. Trying to understand as much as possible since it's my first time using html, javascript etc

Comment: I think there isn't. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLCollection itself suggests using `Array.from()`, if you need a copy you have full control over. But that one you have in your code already.